# Ambari only server gzip encoded resources, which my proxy blocks

Tags: ambari

I am using Ambari behind an old corporate proxy server which does not allow Accept-Encoding headers to be passed through. As a result, Ambari can't serve up javascript or css files. How can I get it to support plain encoding?

Answer (score 1):

The Ambari build process gzips all resources and removed the originals, which is not a bad thing, unless you're dealing with older proxies such as this. To create original plain encoded versions of the relevant assets, which will be served automatically by content negotiation in Ambari, just run

```
for a in /usr/lib/ambari-server/web/{javascripts,stylesheets}/*.gz; do gzip -dc $a > ${a%.gz}; done
```

as root on your ambari-server.